# Text-align не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    .div-middle p{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```js
page.onmousedown = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
body{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 2000px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

header{
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width:100%;
filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px black);
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
z-index: 1;
}
header a[href="hui"]{
  border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
bottom: 55px;
left: 650px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}
a[href='zakup']{
background: Aqua;
padding: 12px 32px;
border-radius: 8px;
}
a[href="fuck"]{

position: relative;
left: 200px;

}


.top-div{
background: grey;
color: white;
padding-top: 10px;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
top: 80px;
z-index: 0;

}
.div-middle{
position: relative;
margin-left: 200px;
top: 300px;
}.div-middle h1{
font-size: 80px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}.div-middle h2{
  margin-top:-4px;
font-size: 34px;
}.div-middle h3{
font-size: 4ch;
position: relative;
left:30px;
margin-top: 60px;
} .div-middle p{
  text-align: left;
}



#page{
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: 23px;
font-family: 'Lexend Exa', sans-serif;
width: min-content;
padding-right: 20px;
border-right: 1px solid white;
letter-spacing: -2px;

}
#market{

color: blue;

}
#landing{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif ;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 610px;

  color: white;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
#section{
background: Gainsboro;
height: 120vh;
}
#pseudo-button{
border: 1px solid orange;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 6px 8px;
color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
      qwe
    </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend+Exa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
  <body>
<header>
 <p id="page"><a href="#"> onepage<span id="market">market</span>.com</a></p>
<span id="landing">ДЛЯ ПРИОБРЕТЕНИЯ ЭТОГО LANDING PAGE ШАБЛОНА НАЖМИТЕ НА КНОПКУ</span>
<a href="hui">КУПИТЬ LANDING PAGE</a>
</header>
<section class="top-div"  >
  <a href="fuck"><img src="https://onepagemarket.ru/wp-content/themes/onepagemarket/base/besprovodnye-naushniki-isonge-10/logo_rhkbbwe.png" alt="">iSonge</a>
</section>
<section id="section">
  <div class="div-middle">
    <span id="pseudo-button">New</span>
    <h1>iSong</h1>
    <h2>Новация на рынке наушников</h2>
    <p>Лучшие беспроводные наушники на рынке, идеально качество звучания и удобная форма позволят насладиться вашей любимой музыкой везде и всегда</p>
    <h3>2990р</h3>
    <a href="zakup">заказать</a>
  </div>

</section>





<script src="qwer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Посоветуйте что-то другое, если text-align тут не сработает. Не судите строго.

Comment: Что именно не работает? Видно же, что содержимое `<p>` выравнивается по левому краю. Скриншот:  http://bit.ly/31BttVf

Answer (score 0):

Я идиот, я хотел что-то вроде этого

```
  .div-middle p{
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/390562)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics , я ответил на свой вопрос

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer